# PlaceHolder Image not animated in imageView in objective C

Tags: ios, iphone

I have use sdWebImage for set the image using the url. and also use the gif image on the placeholder. but the image not animated.

Anybody can help me.

Comment: AFAIK,gif don't work on iOS.

Comment: Like its a static image, you have to use library for GIF image

Comment: If i will use 4 image at the placeholder of imageView. Then how can it possible like animated.

Comment: https://github.com/mattt/AnimatedGIFImageSerialization Use this library

Comment: Or can you provide the link for the third party which is helpful for setting the placeholder animated image.

Comment: this library can be support for the placehoder image of imageView?

Comment: I use the url for the image but at the placeholder side i want to use gif image.

Comment: - (void)setImageWithURL:(NSURL *)url placeholderImage:(UIImage *)placeholder options:(SDWebImageOptions)options progress:(SDWebImageDownloaderProgressBlock)progressBlock completed:(SDWebImageCompletedBlock)completedBlock

Answer (score 0):

You can not directly display gif using placeholder image. For that you need to flow the steps.

1) Set GIF image using sdwebimage method: `setImageWithURLFromSDWebImage:`.

2) Download your actual image with async method using block.

3) After complete download of the image, set original image and replace the GIF.

By this method you can archive your requirement.

You can also create one global method to do that for you ..

Thanks.

Comment: I am using the UICollectionView for more images. And want to set gif image at the placeholder of imageView. Can you give me the coding part.please

Comment: your coding is in swift or obj-C? @HariMohan

Comment: you can do it your own. I did not have implemented this feature. But you can archive this by doing these steps..

Comment: I am using Objective C and i set the image in collectionView Cell like as show below:-

    [cell.ImgV sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dic valueForKey:@"resim1"]]] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"loading.gif"]];